# Is this modular arithmetic matrix transformation valid?

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

In $\mathbb{Z}_5$, are both of these transformations valid or one is incorrect?

$ \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr) \xrightarrow[R_{2}\leftrightarrow 3R_{2}]{} \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) $

$ \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \end{smallmatrix}\bigr) \xrightarrow[R_{2}\leftrightarrow \frac{R_{2}}{2}]{} \bigl(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 & 4 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr) $

I wonder whether there are any exceptions where you cannot divide when performing matrix transformations in modular arithmetic.

Comment: You can multiply a row by any invertible element $a$ of $\Bbb Z_n$ (like $3$ or $2$ in $\Bbb Z_5$), since such a transformation has an inverse transformation: multiplication of the same row by $a^{-1}.$

Comment: This has nothing to do with transformations. $\Bbb F_5$ is a field, and we have $2\cdot 3=1$ in the first case, and hence $2^{-1}=3$. So both are the same, $3R_2=R_2/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

Both are the same in $\mathbb{Z_5}$: $3R_2=\frac{R_2}{2}$

This is because $2^{−1}=3$ in $\mathbb{Z_5}$.